# Proper way to reuse UITableViewCell containing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView. Each cell contains horizontal collection view. When I scroll the table, collection view contains too much cells. I guess it is because the cells are not properly reused. In the illustration, the grey cells were not suppose to be there. 
[image: table view]

What is the proper code that I should put in the reuseCell? I tried the following but it made the app crash

over

```
ride func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        channelsCollectionView = UICollectionView()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
//Reset the datasource
channelsCollectionView.dataSourceArray = []()

//Reload data of collectionView
channelsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Again its depends, this is one way of doing

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below steps. That will work perfectly fine CollectionView inside UITableViewCell.

1. Make subclass of **UICollectionView** like this.

   ```
   @interface MyCollectionView : UICollectionView <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

   /* Properties */
   @property (nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableArray *imagesArray;

   @end
   ```
2. In your **MyCollectionView**.m file

   ```
   @interface MyCollectionView ()

   @property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout;

   @end

   @implementation MyCollectionView

   -(void)awakeFromNib {

       [super awakeFromNib];

       self.dataSource = self;
       self.delegate = self;

       //Set CollectionView Layout
       [self setCollectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
   }

   #pragma mark - CollectionView DataSource methods
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
      return 1;
   }

   -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return _imagesArray.count;
   }


   -(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout{

     // set your layout here
    _flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [_flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topSpacing, leftMargin, bottomSpacing, rightMargin)];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:cellSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:lineSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [_flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight)];

    return _flowLayout;
   }

   #pragma mark - setter method
   -(void)setImagesArray:(NSMutableArray *)imagesArray {

    _imagesArray = imagesArray;
     [self reloadData];

   }

   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      // configure cell here

   }
   ```
3. In your **ViewController**.m having **UITableView**

   ```
       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

          MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

          cell.myCollectionView.imagesArray = //Array here

          return cell;

        }
   ```
4. You need to set fix height of your collectionView in TableViewCell. As you've horizontal collectionView.